# What are the export controls of block cipher?

Tags: security, encryption, blockcypher

What are meant by export controls of block cipher  ? I am new here . So I would be much thankful to you if you could supply some explanation with this .
Thank you !

Comment: That may be pretty complex topic (even legally), so what context do you need yo know ? just search the net and then you rather ask a specific question what is not clear

Comment: 'block' is irrelevant here; when export controls apply (or try to) they apply to all kinds of ciphers equally. This is _mostly_ an issue for export from US, and the second google hit for 'export controls cipher' is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States which is a good overview, with links as usual for wikipedia; that search gives other useful pages as well.

Comment: Why this is appearing in the edit review and not being closed or deleted is beyond me.